# UISearchBar Not appearing

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have view controller, into the view i have put a table view, and a search bar into the table's header... the search bar is not showing up, just the empty table view.

Do i need to do something additional? I'm pretty sure its to do with the `view` outlet of the UIViewController, set to `View`...

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed using a UISearchBar with controller.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else who may be landing on this question, I had a very similar situation where a UITableViewController with a UISearchBar added to it wasn't displaying.  If you find yourself in this situation, double check that you are actually calling:

```
initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil
```

to init your view controller instead of the common Table View init of:

```
initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain
```

I was foolishly adding the search bar to the Nib, and then loading it with the style init (which skips the Nib entirely and loads the table view from scratch)

Comment: This helped, I was passing nil to initWithNibName, which usually works but for UITableViewControllers it seems to not.

Answer (score 2):

try setting the tableHeaderView of your tableView to your searchBar.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

if you are using IB, be sure to connect the outlets so that it gets referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,l it worked for me:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
     [_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
}

-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,MAX(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y),320,44);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your view controller as a part of tabbar controller, besides "Class" property in IB set the "NIB name" property. It takes me several hours to figure it out.