# UITableView header is not visible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to add search bar to UITableView header, it's visible on IB but not on emulator after running

Comment: can you add some code,how you are actually adding it?

Comment: i do it on Interface Builder, just drag searchbar to the tableview header, after that IB resizes the tableview and put the searchbar to the header, but when application starts nothing was happened

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556216/uisearchbar-not-appearing

Comment: Yeaah it works, thanks RIP, i have noticed that any changes on my nib files does not affect to the view result and there is also initWithStyle instead of initWithnibName on tableViewcontroller initialization, and i pass the nib name inside the initWithNibName method by calling 
self=[super initWithNibName:@"mynibname" bundle:nibBundleOrNil]; because when it is null system does not automatically find the nib file

Comment: great!!!!then you can post this as answer and can accept that and close this question.

Comment: how to post this as an answer and close the question? :)

Comment: in answer section, you can provide details whatever you did to solve this issue. And after posting that answer, select the check button that appear side of your answer.

Comment: maybe you will answer the question and i will mark it as a answer, because i have no such reputation to answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are actually calling- `initWithNibName: bundle:`  method properly.

Answer (score -1):

Actually headers are the part of section in table view, so ur view controller class must conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol and must implements the method
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

and for customization of ur header view use
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

example
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 25.0f;
}

or you can use UITableViewDataSource method
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return @"#";
}

Comment: Table views also have table view-wide headers and footers that are independent of section headers.